# Change selection of a QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am using a QTreeWidget to display some items. I have only a single column and my tree has a depth of two. I would like to add the following functionality: If a top-level item is selected/deselected and it is not expanded, then its children should be selected/deselected as well. The question is how I can find out when the selection changes.

I am subclassing QTreeWidget for my custom widget. I could connect to the selectionChanged() slot of the QTreeWidget, but in that case, I would have to loop over all top-level items, find out if their selection state has changed (so I would also need to store selection states), and update everything accordingly.

I think there should be a selectionChanged() signal which provides some more information about the selection, but I can't find anything in the documentation. Any ideas about this?

Comment: Did you look at `QAbstractItemView::selectionChanged(const QItemSelection &selected, const QItemSelection &deselected)`? This is a virtual function that you can override in your custom QTreeWidget subclass.

Comment: Well, that gives me a number of `QItemSelectionRange`s, but I want the actual `QTreeWidgetItem*`s which have been selected...

Comment: You can get the list of selected QModelIndexes from `QItemSelection:: indexes()` and than use `QTreeWidget::itemFromIndex()` function to get `QTreeWidgetItem`.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I need to find the items which are *newly* selected, otherwise the program will loop forever...

Answer (score 0):

By selection/deselection of children, do you mean they should get expanded(and if selected)?
And one more suggestion instead of using QTreeWidget, I think QTreeView is a better choice if you can explain the issue a bit more maybe I can provide some sample code

Comment: Well, I draw some stuff in another widget depending on the selected items. The idea is that users select some top-level elemts first to draw the depending elements in lower levels as well and only manually switches those off if they want to...